# Calculate concordance index in Python

Tags: python, automation, calculation

I would like to replicate a concordance index I read about in a [paper](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/79990/1/MPRA_paper_79990.pdf), however - unfortunately - I am not able to automate the calculation in Python. Hence, I am wondering if one of you could help me, please.

I have a matrix with m rows and n columns, where the rows m contain the observations X, Y, etc. and the columns contain binary values for X,Y, etc. over t. Now I would like to compare rows according to their values in time and write the results in a matrix with the following formula:

[image: concordance_formula]

The results should then be a symmetric matrix, however, I am unfortunately not too familiar with Python and do not know how to automate the "comparison". I generated a small example in Excel which can be downloaded on WeTransfer here: [WeTransfer](https://transfernow.net/c1glqdkf2si9)

I would be very glad if someone could help me, please.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards
Alex

Comment: Anyone, please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue with the following code I wrote:

```
data = pd.read_excel("...", index_col=[0], header_col=[0])


import time
start_time = time.time()


results = []
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    for j in range(0,len(data)):
        result_i =(1/len(data.columns))*(sum(data.iloc[i]*data.iloc[j]+(1-data.iloc[i])*(1-data.iloc[j])))
        results += [result_i]


matrix = []
while results != []:
    matrix.append(results[:1680])
    results = results[1680:]

matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
```